# Vue compare variable to sibling components data

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm using Vue to create an app where I have

- App Component

  - Create User Form Component
  - Users Component

My **Users Component** is holding the users array as following

```
export default {
    components: {
        User
    },
    data() {
        return {
            users: []
        }
    },
}
```

My users array holds different User objects in the Users Component

[image]

> In my Create User Form Component I'm getting an id from my API, This id has to be unique in the users array. The issue is the users array is in the Users Component.

So I don't know how to reach this users array from in my sibling component.

Thank you!

Comment: You should take a look at Vuex - storing the users in a Vuex state would make this easier. https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/

Comment: You can put the `users` array in the parent component, and pass it down as props. This way both components have access to `users`. Or use Vuex

Comment: 3rd option : Don't use component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone already mentioned in a comment to you, your life will be a whole lot easier if you used something like Vuex: https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/

Now, people often avoid this by saying something like "it's only a simple app, I don't need that complexity". But in my mind, Vuex is very straight-forward and much simpler than something like Redux, if React happens to be your experience. It will save you a ton of time and code later down the line too.

The concept is simple enough; store your users in a top-level accessible store. Now every component can reach to the store instead of getting messy trying to pass users around to one another via events and props.

**Vuex Example Store:**

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    users: [
      { id: 1, credits: 1, name: "Michael", tagid: "1" },
      { id: 2, credits: 2, name: "Kate", tagid: "2" }
    ]
  },
  getters: {
    allUsers: state => {
      return state.users
    }
  }
})
```

**Component Example Getting All Users From Store:**

*JavaScript*

```
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters([
      'allUsers'
    ])
  }
}
```

*Template*

```
<template>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="user in allUsers" :key="user.id">{{ user.name }}</li>
  </ul>
</template>
```

This is all untested example code, but hopefully you can see where I'm going with this.

It would also be very helpful if you used the [Vue.js Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd?hl=en) or [Vue.js devtools for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/vue-js-devtools/), which has a Vuex tab built in that allows you to examine the store.

Good luck!